# How to index several 2d numpy arrays with different number of rows in a 3d array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have the following problem in python: I have several numpy 2d-arrays where all have same number of columns ,but different number of rows.I want to index all these 2d-array in a unique numpy 3d-array where the first index keeps into account each 2d-array.
For example :
let's suppose I got two 2d-arrays like this :
[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]] (3X3 array)
[[11,12,13][14,15,16]]  (2X3 array)

I want to get a numpy 3d-array name,for example, c where : c[0] has shape (3,3), c[1] (2,3) and so on...So I expect a 3d-array whose shape is (number of 2d matrices,number of rows of one matrix,number of columns of one matrix)

How can I reshape since each 2d-arrays have different number of rows each other?
Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that what you want could rather be a _list_ of 2D arrays, `ABCD = [A, B, C, D]` where `A` etc are your 2D arrays.

Comment: Well, I need to build a buch object for my dataset.My idea is to have between all data structures inside my buch object one that can index my datafiles(that are numpy 2d array ). Problem is that each 2d-array has different number of rows, so this is the difficulty to convert them into a single numpy 3d array.

Comment: What is wrong with a list? say that you put the data sets into a list: `buch = [A, B, C, ...]`, next you can get `C` as `buch[2]`, you can iterate on data sets with a for loop, `for data_set in buch: ...` etc etc etc. The only thing that you are going to miss is some algebraic shortcuts... In my opinion, if what you want is a container then a list is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo , I meant a bunch python class not  buch as generic object.

Comment: My external container has to be a bunch python class and one of the data structure inside it is  a 3d-array ,as explained above. The advantage would be that I could manipulate a dictionary like an object.