# How to make a Numpy 3D array with different length in the 2nd dimension?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have some code that constructs a 3D numpy array (x_3d) on the fly using values from a 2D numpy array (x) in a forloop

```
x_3d = np.empty((0, 20, 10))
for i in range(num_samples):
    x_3d = np.append(x_3d, [x[i*20:(i+1)*20, :]],
                     axis=0)
```

The resulting shape of the 3D array is (num_samples, 20, 10).

If I want to take slices of different length from the 2D array so that the number of rows varies how can I do that?  I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024847/how-to-index-several-2d-numpy-arrays-with-different-number-of-rows-in-a-3d-array).  By storing the 2D arrays initially in a list, and then transform the list back to an array gave me the shape of (num_samples, ), while each element is a 2D numpy array it is not a 3D numpy array with the shape of (num_samples, length_varies, 10).

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking.  But if you're trying to make a jagged numpy array, just don't.  numpy isn't meant to deal with that.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make a jagged numpy array.  Thank you for your help :)